# Regex - Match javascript variables in html source code

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have a webpage with javascript inside and I need to match 2 variables passed to a function:

```
<html>
<!--Some html code-->
document.write(function('variable1', 'variable2'));
<!--Some html code-->
</html>
```

variable1 and variable2 can be strings of any lenght with mixed characters and digits. I need to match them both. This is what I use now:

```
data = getSoup(url) # my function to get the beautifulsoup object
script = data.find('script', text = re.compile(r'document\.write\(function\(')).text.replace('document.write(function(\'', '')
variable1 = script.split("', '")[0]
variable2 = script.split("', '")[1].replace("'));","")
```

But I would like to use something more simple and "safe" (even because not always the function is insite a script tag.

**Update:**
Thanks to **Thomas Ayoub** answer I found a simple solution working for me:

```
script = re.findall(r"document\.write\(function\(\'(.*?)\', \'(.*?)\'\)\)\;", str(data))[0]
variable1 = script[0]
variable2 = script[1]
```

Comment: long story short, you want to remove `document.write(function('variable1', 'variable2'));` from `text` no matter the names of the variables?

Comment: I need to extract the 2 variables into 2 python variables, whatever the variables are. I was thinking to a regex like "document\.write\(function\('(.*?)', '(.*?)'\)\);" but I don't know how to match the 2 variables

Comment: Something like [this](https://ideone.com/oUZxYQ)?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub yeah it works but your code is too much complex for me! I need to match only the first group found on the page and extract variables into python variables like var1 = variable1

Comment: Is this [better](https://ideone.com/oUZxYQ)?

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer yourself and then, mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
regex = r"document\.write\(function\(\s*'([^']+)'\s*,\s*'([^']+)'\s*\)"
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/oUZxYQ)